# get product by name or from name

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, usage

Is there a difference between:

- "get product by id" and "get product from id"
- "get product by name" and "get product from name"

Comment: You have accepted the answer too fast. I thought that you were talking about programming, about retrieving an object of type product. That context got nothing to do with sending or receiving an email.

Comment: @RubioRic I think yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that you have specified that we are talking about programming. Probably you know about SQL, the universal language used to execute queries on a database. Its main sentence is a SELECT query

> SELECT ATTRIBUTE
>  **FROM** PRODUCTS
>  WHERE CONDITION

I've highlighted the preposition **from**, it marks the place **where** the objects are stored. Which specific objects PRODUCTS we want to retrieve are filtered **by** the condition.

> SELECT *
>  **FROM** PRODUCTS
>  WHERE id = 5
>
> SELECT *
>  **FROM** PRODUCTS
>  WHERE name = 'Richard'

When we retrieve one specific object from PRODUCT using its id as condition, we say that we are selecting the object **by** id.

I don't know the exact programming language that you use but as an example, you can check Spring JPA library, that got structures like [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer>, Long> {
     List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName); 
}
```

find**By**LastName means that all retrieved Customers will have that lastName.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this,may be you got the point why we use by or from.

```
Email received by you
Someone else sent an email to you. It was received by you.

Email received from you.
You sent an email to someone else. They received it from you.
```